# SDL Releases the Cumulative Update 1 for SDL Web 8, SDL Web Experience Optimization 8 and SDL Digital Experience Accelerator 1.4

Tags: discussion

Did everybody know that the [SDL Web Q1 update which was previously described on SDL Community](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/b/weblog/archive/2016/03/01/sdl-web-q1-2016-update) is now available as the **Cumulative Update 1 for SDL Web 8**?

This cumulative update is a convenient and low-impact way to stay up-to-date with the Web 8 line and should be installed on top of Web 8 installations. As per SDLs latest release policy, they will be providing regular cumulative updates, allowing their customers to stay current.

The Cumulative Update 1 for SDL Web 8 features several enhancements for IT, including:

- separated Preview Service and Session-enabled Content Service which enhances security between the Content Manager and Presentation server
- installers allowing you to quickly install multiple microservices in bulk
- auto-registration of microservices, reducing manual configuration
- rich management of microservices, enabling you to easily add, edit and delete Capabilities
- reduced dependencies on third-party libraries, allowing for more freedom in development and easier upgrades
- use of parameters in the Storage Layer configuration file allowing for customization through startup commands

## SDL Web Experience Optimization 8

SDL Web Experience Optimization, formerly called SDL SmartTarget, lets you create and manage targeted content for websites powered by SDL Web. This release brings Web 8 compatibility and the following changes:

- Regions are now managed through an automatically created Region trigger, removing the need for configuration file updates
- Schema Fields can be excludes across an entire BluePrint, simplifying the maintenance of this configuration

## Digital Experience Accelerator 1.4

In addition, SDL also have a new version of the Digital Experience Accelerator (DXA). DXA is a fully functional website implementation solution for SDL Web, using responsive design techniques and the latest web standards. It provides a quick-start foundation for web projects, based on years of implementation experience, decreasing website implementation time by up to 70%.

This latest release of the Digital Experience Accelerator now includes the Experience Optimization module for SDL Web 8, which puts you in control of state-of-the-art personalization and targeting practices out of the box. It also delivers a new project structure in the Java version, giving subprojects an independent life cycle, which allows you to release changes independently, without requiring a full rebuild.

The DXA framework is directly available for developers in the form of NuGet packages and Maven artifacts that are dependent on the SDL Web Content Interaction Libraries artifacts.

You can find [details on the Cumulative Update 1 for SDL Web 8 on the SDL Documentation Center](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-35A551C9-FE77-47CD-A547-3EC8FEB4B9B6), details on the [DXA 1.4 reference implementation here](https://docs.sdl.com/sdldxa14), and an extensive description of how to install, configure and use Experience Optimization (or XO for short) on top of your Web 8 suite in the [XO for Web 8 documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-5C1B08DC-1C99-479D-8D8D-D459D857C755) and through [Installing the XO module for DXA](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-4EF2CBD3-2FD6-4E52-A625-27381D040C6E).

For more information on all of the changes please, check the online documentation on the [SDL Documentation Center](https://docs.sdl.com/).